# Create a connection to Oracle database from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, apache

I am writing a PHP file to read some log files and write the content to Oracle database. I try to create a connection to the database as following.

```
$conn = oci_pconnect('myservice','oracle123','192.168.0.126:2483/XE');

if (!$conn) {
  $e = oci_error();
  echo trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Here is my full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$conn = oci_pconnect('robiservice','oracle123','192.168.0.26:2483/XE');

if (!$conn) {
 $e = oci_error();
 echo trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
} 

$myfile = fopen("14121800_ussd_cdr.file", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($myfile) {
 while (($line = fgets($myfile)) !== false) {
    echo $line . "</br>";
}
} else {
 // error opening the file.
} 
fclose($myfile);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am running my code in apache server. I put the code into htcocs folder.

But the problem is it gives a blank page. I think I need to install Oracle drivers in the server. But since I am a newbie to this I don't have clear idea about how to do it properly.

Any Suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: First of all enable your PHP-error-reporting in your development environment, so you won't get a blank page, but an error message.

Comment: Can you please check the server log and post it here if it has an error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need Oracle Instant Client, Pecl, and oci8 driver.
Oracle manual:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html

Answer (score 0):

I have created a connection in Zend framework as follows:

**Step 1.** In `application/config/application.ini` set your database parameters:

```
resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "Oracle"
resources.multidb.db2.charset = "utf8"
resources.multidb.db2.host = "183.19.163.149/pankaj_india"
resources.multidb.db2.port = "1521"
resources.multidb.db2.username = "username"
resources.multidb.db2.password = "password"
resources.multidb.db2.dbname = "databasname"
```

**Step 2.** Download the "InstantClient Package - Basic" for Windows from the [OTN InstantClient page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). Because PHP is 32 bit, use the 32 bit version of InstantClient.

**Step 3.** Unzip the InstantClient files to `C:\instantclient_11_2` and edit the Windows PATH environment to include `C:\instantclient_11_2`. For example, on Windows XP, follow `Start > Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables` and edit `PATH` in the `System` variables list.

**Step 4.** In your `php.ini` file, enable the following lines:

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Finally, restart your Apache server.

Comment: Please take the time to read about [how to format your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and then edit your answer(s). Currently it is very difficult to read and will only attract downvotes from other users.

Comment: thanks  but I tried lot and emphasize how to format post

Comment: I have edited your answer to demonstrate the use of formatting. Take note of the differences and strive to improve for your future answers.

Comment: Thanks dear I will do same as you suggest